# Rebuild docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

i reckon that there are lots of questions regarding this issue, but i've tried pretty much everything and it doesn't work for my case.

I'm a beginner in Docker, and I have cloned a docker from github which deploys a webapp using nginx, the first build was successful, i got to access localhost:381 and find it, but when i changed some of the code and rebuilt it (after running docker-compose down i ran docker-compose up --build --no-cache), i still cannot see the updates. I thought the image was not updated so i deleted it, deleted the container and the volume and i can still access the webapp still from localhost:381. I rebuilt it again and i still can't see the updates.
Any help?

Comment: Not clear - did you restart working container?

Comment: Can you post the docker-compose.yml and maybe the Dockerfile? Looks like your code is not really copied to the image

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Comment: So why rebuild for? While developing you can mount your directory to a directory inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

this will recreate all current containers using the new code.

Comment: This did not work for me. i.e. I made a change to my code, ran the command, looked at the app in the browser and the changes had not taken place. Even ran it in incognito mode just to make sure that cache wasn't an issue. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: same problem for me

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58447105/1344633) works for me: `docker-compose build --no-cache`