# docker-compose flag to always rebuild docker container?

Tags: docker-compose

this is a part of my docker-compose file:

```
super-nice-service:
    build: ./Path/To/Dockerfile/
```

is there a flag i can add so this project is always getting rebuild whenever i do "docker-compose up" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no single command to do build and compose up you can try below, this will do a clean build of containers and bring the services up

```
docker-compose rm --all &&
 docker-compose pull &&
 docker-compose build --no-cache &&
 docker-compose up -d --force-recreate &&
```

Comment: okay that is bad :/ . What iam doing now is just removing this single image: docker image rm imageName which forces a rebuild of this particular project